# xlsx reading through apache poi

Tags: android, apache-poi, watchdog

I just need to select a XLSX file from my sd card and read it through apache poi. here is my intent call to sd card and choose the xlsx file

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("*/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_FILE);
    }
```

Here is code for receiving the path of selected .xlsx file here is the error generating i think its on calling the workbook but i cant clear it

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_FILE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


       // File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), data.getData().toString());
        Uri path =data.getData();
        ContentResolver cr=this.getContentResolver();
        File fpath=new File(path.toString());


        try {
            //imputStream
            InputStream myfile=cr.openInputStream(path);
            Log.e("myapp","here");
            //Workbooh
            Workbook wrk=new HSSFWorkbook(myfile);


            //sheet
            Sheet firstsheet=wrk.getSheetAt(0);

            //RowIterator
            Iterator<Row> iterator=firstsheet.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext())
            {
                Row next=iterator.next();

                //CellIterator
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator=next.cellIterator();
                while(cellIterator.hasNext())
                {
                    Cell cell=cellIterator.next();

                    switch (cell.getCellType())
                    {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),cell.getStringCellValue()+" ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),cell.getNumericCellValue()+" ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


    }
```

my error list given below

```
 04-26 12:18:17.067 2736-3126/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1540 [04-26 12:18:17.069]
 04-26 12:18:47.067 2736-3126/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1541 [04-26 12:18:47.072]
 04-26 12:19:17.067 2736-3126/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1542 [04-26 12:19:17.073]
 04-26 12:19:47.072 2736-3126/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1543 [04-26 12:19:47.075]
 04-26 12:20:17.072 2736-3126/? E/Watchdog: !@Sync 1544 [04-26 12:20:17.076]
```

thanks for help in advance.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the catch - e.printStackTrace(), this likely hides the actual exception that you get. You better review how to log these correctly.

And take a look at https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx, it provides some workarounds for issues when using Apache POI on Android.